# Java Robot doesn't work on fedora?

Tags: java, linux, x11, fedora, awtrobot

```
try{
    Robot rob = new Robot();
    for(int i = 0; i < 30; ++i) {
        double rr = Math.random();
        rob.mouseMove((int) (rr * 200), (int) (rr * 300));
        System.out.println("x=" + (int) (rr * 200) + ", y=" + (int) (rr * 300));
        rob.delay(300);
    }
} catch(Exception e){
    System.exit(-1);
}
```

Above code works perfectly on my windows 7, but doesn't seem to work on my Fedora 27? There's no error msg, no exceptions, I do see the System.out.println() being executed 30 times, but the mouse does not move all all. What did I miss?

Comment: Are you sure you are using X11 as your tag suggests? Fedora now uses Wayland, not X11, at least for some desktop environments.